# What method to use for voting in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I have many quotes on the website and I want user to be able to vote, Like or Unlike each quote. The problem is that if I save the voted info in a cookie, there is a 4kb limit and if there is a visitor which votes on 100 quotes it may exceed the cookie limit.

What is the best method to store the vote information for non logged users?

The votes are also stored in database, but without any user information saved. Only logged users have saved info for each vote.

Comment: Create an anonymous connection, the cookie with the vote of each user - on your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save votes on a table with columns:

- quoteid,
- userguid (guid)

And set a cookie on nonregistered users browser with an assigned GUID

when a user visit your site check the user GUID or assign him a new one. This way you can block votes.

Comment: The problem with this is that the database will grow very quickly. But until now it seems the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Comment: it is complicated to use and with javascript, also not compatible with all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I would assign the non-logged in user a random ID and store this ID in the cookie.

The Id can then be used to reference data in your database.